# docker container fails to start with docker-compose exit status 2, code 128

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two Docker images that I start as a linked pair.  Now trying to use Compose to automate the startup process.   My compose file:

```
apacheserver:
  image: 172.17.81.99:5000/apache-http-server-fedora
  links:
    - libertyserver:liberty
  ports:
    - 9081:9080
    - 3023:22
  volumes:
    - /var/docker_data_repository:/var/hostfiles
libertyserver:
  image: 172.17.81.99:5000/liberty-server-fedora
  ports:
    - 9080:9080
    - 3022:22
  volumes:
    - /var/docker_data_repository:/var/hostfiles
```

This fails like this:

```
...
docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'',
 u'Args': [u'-c', u'/startup/docker-liberty-startup.sh'],
 u'Config': {u'AttachStderr': True,
             u'AttachStdin': False,
             u'AttachStdout': True,
             u'Cmd': [u'/bin/sh',
                      u'-c',
                      u'/startup/docker-liberty-startup.sh'],
             u'CpuShares': 0,
             u'Cpuset': u'',
...
docker start <- (u'77a19fb191637f6b969cd6315acfd7965319c8a2f6caa3d19055855936ae56aa')
Cannot start container 77a19fb191637f6b969cd6315acfd7965319c8a2f6caa3d19055855936ae56aa:  (exit status 2)
```

If I look at the generated container it says:

```
...
    "State": {
        "Error": " (exit status 2)",
        "ExitCode": 128,
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
```

The content of the inspect log isn't obviously different than a container that successfully starts, other than the instance details.  I haven't found any explanation of these exit codes that seems to apply to this scenario.  Is there a way to get any more detailed information from Docker about the cause of the failure?